# Quotient groups of $\mathbb{RxR}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Quotient groups of $\mathbb{RxR}$
>
> > In each of the following, H is a subset of  $\mathbb{RxR}$.
>
> a) Prove that H is a normal subgroup of  $\mathbb{RxR}$ (Remember that
>   every subgroup of an abelian group is normal)
>
> b) In geometric terms, describe the elements of the quotient group
>   $G/H$
>
> c) In geometrical terms or otherwise describe the operation of $G/H$
>
> where $H=\{(x,y):y=-x\}$

This is what I've done so far:

**a)** Since $\mathbb{RxR}$ is abelian and we are given that H is a subset, then we must show that H is a subgroup first. This means that H has an inverse and is closed with respected to addition.

H has an identity $(0,0)$ and an inverse $(-a,-b)$ for $a,b \in H$. Also, for $a,b,c,d \in H$. then we have: $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)=(a+c,-a+-c)$ which is in $H$, therefore closed with respect to addition.

Thus, $H$ is a subgroup

The thereom that states every subgroup of an abelian group is normal. We know $H$ is normal since $\mathbb{RxR}$ is abelian

**b)** To describe the elements of the quotient group $G/H$, I started with the definition. $G/H$ is the set of cosets of $H$ in $G$. For this case, I am going to stick with right cosets. I am not sure what this is asking for, so I decided to list some elements.

We know that $G$ be in the form $(x,y),(-x,-y),(-x,y),(x,-y)$ where $x,y$ are integers in $G$ The reals also contain the rationals so we can also have $(\frac{a}{b},y)$ and so on .... where $a,b$ are integers as well

So the cosets $H+g$ where $g \in G$ will be the same. It can contain (0,0), positive or negative integers and positive or negative rationals.

So I'm not sure how I can describe this actually, if anyone can help with this part.

**c)** I believe the operation for $G/H$ is addition.

Comment: Since $H$ is closed under scalar multiplication, why not consider it a linear subspace and finish faster..?

Comment: I thought it was closed under addition?

Comment: It has to be closed under addition to be a subgroup, and this is true and you show it. What I'm saying is that this particular $H$ also happens to be closed under scalar multiplication -can you see why?- so you can treat it as a linear subspace...

Comment: I am probably not seeing it because I thought that the subgroup needs to have the same operation as the group and I dont think $\mathbb{RxR}$ is closed under multiplication. The only thing I could think is your involving the distributive property so the operation appears as multiplication but is in fact addition.

Comment: If $(x,y)\in H$, then $y=-x$. Then $\lambda y=-\lambda x$, so $(\lambda x, \lambda y)\in H$ also... This means $H$ is closed under _scalar_ multiplication... Same is true for  $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ ...

Comment: I see, so if I consider it as a linear subspace, would that help me with part b?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22724/discussion-between-theo-and-emmie).

Comment: If you need any help tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: in particular, $H$ is an element (the zero element) of $G/H$.  What does it look like geometrically?  Can you graph it?  Once you know that, the other cosets are just translates of $H$, so they should look the same, just moved around.  For instance, what does the coset $(0,1) + H$ look like?

Comment: I graphed some points and I obtained linear lines. As for (0,1), I picked (1,-1), (2,-2), (-3,3) and I get a linear line. I get it now. thanks.